# Get rid of box border of ImageIcon

Tags: java, user-interface, button

Okay I am having a little problem. As soon as you press a button in my application, I load a local loading.gif icon into it but the problem I am having as you can see from the first image below is the weird blue box around it. Any ideas on how I can get rid of it?
[image]

What I have tried so far:

`login.setSelected(false)`  Did nothing
`login.setEnabled`  Makes a weird gray box around the image like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yay I figured it out...Guess should have waited before posting. If anyone cares for a solution, I simply set `login.setFocusable(false);` and it worked!

Comment: You could also try `setFocusPainted(false)`

Comment: 1) That simple solution means the user can no longer easily activate the button using the keyboard. 2) Button icons were meant to represent a button states such as pressed, mouse-over, selected etc. rather that a 'loading status'.  More commonly that would be displayed in a pop-up of some sort, or a generic space in the app. designed for showing progress. ..(reconsiders) actually the Kindle reader has a button just like that..  3) In summary, this approach seems unusual (hard to understand) & (at least slightly) unworkable.